# Can you default to HTTPS in .htaccess RewriteRules when behind an SSL terminated load balancer?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently we went HTTPS everywhere. Apache sits behind SSL-terminated load balancers and we started noticing that this kind of rule:

```
# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([A-Za-z0-9\-\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$
RewriteRule .* /%1/ [R=301,L]
```

Would redirect `https://www.foo.com/bar` to `http://www.foo.com/bar/` (followed by another redirect to switch to SSL).

I know we can do something along the lines of this to the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

But, if there are a lot of rules, **is there a more elegant way of always redirecting to the `https://` version**, such as a default/base protocol, without needing to change every rule to have the `https://%{HTTP_HOST}/` prefix for the replacement?